# How could I load MongoDB Client and start a connection inside F# Interactive?

Tags: mongodb, f#, f#-interactive

I'm using netcore 3.1, on macOS Catalina 10.15.6, and JetBrains Rider 2020.2 .

I tried starting a MongoDB connection with the following:

```
#r "../../../.nuget/packages/dnsclient/1.3.1/lib/net471/DnsClient.dll"
#r "../../../.nuget/packages/mongodb.driver.core/2.11.0/lib/net452/MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll"
#r "../../../.nuget/packages/mongodb.bson/2.11.0/lib/net452/MongoDB.Bson.dll"
#r "../../../.nuget/packages/mongodb.driver/2.11.0/lib/net452/MongoDB.Driver.dll"
let connection = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient "someConnectionString"
```

however, when executed, there's still a problem loading the DnsClient assembly, as in the error message below:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DnsClient, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4574bb5573c51424'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'DnsClient, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4574bb5573c51424'
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper..ctor()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper..cctor()


   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper.get_Instance()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder..ctor(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(String connectionString)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0181>.$FSI_0181.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

How to make the MongoDB.Driver.Core refer to the right path for DnsClient?

Comment: A year later and still no good answer on this and I just ran into the problem.  Did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try restore/install all your drivers(mongoDB.Driver.Core and ones depending on),
I got the same error with the following situation :
I have a DAL class library with dependency packages AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDBCore(2.1.1) and MongoDB.Driver.Core(2.11.0), 
An API project which lacked the Identity.MongoDBCore(2.1.1) but had the MongoDB.Driver.Core(2.11.0),

The Dependency container thrawed the DNSClient exception,
{"The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception."}